# get page no from url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to get page no from url

Eg:

```
www.example.com/education/tutorial/php-234.html
```

to

```
PageNo=234
```

and

```
www.example.com/course-1504.html
```

to

```
PageNo=1504
```

I am using the following code in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).html$ Pages.php?PageNo=$1 [NC,L]
```

But it is not working

If we use

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]+).html$ Pages.php?PageNo=$1 [NC,L]
```

I got page no, But

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ Pages.php?PageName=$1 [NC,L]
```

is not working

Any suggestion for both combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ Pages.php?PageName=$1&PageNo=$2 [L,QSA]
```